# Bar diagram strange behaviour

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

My code is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = some title,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {Kesklinn, Mustamae, Kristiine, Nomme, Haabersti, Pohja-Tallinn, Lasnamae},
    nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (0.034,Kesklinn)         (-0.011,Mustamae)
                         (-0.01,Kristiine)  (0.025,Nomme) (0.018,Haabersti) (0.008,Pohja-Tallinn) (0.117,Lasnamae)};


  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The outcome is:
[image]

What i want is to force the name of each bar to appear in a proper place (some do not appear at all) and if the bar is negative i want the name of this bar to be on the right not on the left. Furthermore i want to have nubmer displayed as percentage and i do not want them to be rounded up (as pgfplots did).

Comment: Increase the `enlarge x limits` in a one sided fashion.

Comment: what does it mean in one sided fashion? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Try `enlarge x limits  = {0.5,lower},` that would at least make it more acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question shows some issues:

- **Overlapping:** Percusse already told you how to avoid the overlap of the plots on the y ticks, although a similar result can obtained even with just specifying `enlarge x limits  = 0.6`, and no y limits. Or even no limits at all. You can choose what works for you. I chose none in this case.
- **Ticks don't appear:** The reason why some y ticks don't appear is because you didn't add the option `ytick=data,` before the symbolic coordinates definition.
- **Nodes positioning (to be fixed):** For the nodes on the right, you can add `nodes near coords align={right},` or `anchor=west`. The problem here is that, the negative values will overlap the bar because, being negative, they will attach to the right side of the coordinate, therefore ending up over the bar itself. I don't think there is a way to change this, other than manually shifting all the nodes, because usually people want their nodes near coords in the standard position.

  A possible alternative would be to apply a condition so that only negative values are shifted. But I'm not sure how to do that yet.
- **Percentages:** The nodes near coordinates have been converted to percentages using the following commands:

  ```
  nodes near coords={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%$},
  point meta=100*x,
  ```

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title  = some title,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    ytick=data,
    symbolic y coords={Kesklinn, Mustamae, Kristiine, Nomme, Haabersti, Pohja-Tallinn, Lasnamae},
    y tick label style={anchor=east},
    nodes near coords={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%$},
    point meta=100*x,
    nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
    every node near coord/.append style={%
        xshift=5mm
    }
    ]

\addplot coordinates {
    (0.034,Kesklinn)
    (-0.011,Mustamae)
    (-0.01,Kristiine)
    (0.025,Nomme)
    (0.018,Haabersti)
    (0.008,Pohja-Tallinn) 
    (0.117,Lasnamae)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One more question, how to change those numbers to percentages? I.e. I want 12% not 0.12 etc.

Comment: @mkropkowski how would negative numbers appear? As -1%, for example?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean.

Comment: @mkropkowski Ok, I got that. I'll post my new version soon.

Comment: @mkropkowski Percentages added. I'll let you know if I fix the shifting.

Comment: Appreciate your help!